# C - Position of digit in a number

Tags: c, loops, codeblocks, digits

```
void main()
{
    int i, j = 0, p, q, N;    // N is the integer and p is the position needed
    printf("Enter two positive integers: ");
    scanf("%d%d", &N, &p);  // Taking the values of N and p

    for(i = 1; i <= p; i++) {

        j = N / 10;
        q = j % 10;
        i++;
        j = q;
    }

    printf("The digit of %d in the position %d is %d", N, p, j);
}
```

---

**Example Input:**

<kbd>**Enter two positive integers:

123456789

3**</kbd>

**Output:**

```
The digit of 123456789 in the position 3 is 8
```

---

I actually have 2 problems with the above lines of code:

1. if I use the method above the computer will start taking digits from right to left while usually, the count of digits starts from left to right
2. the program is only repeating itself in the loop which means that it is not taking the new value of `j` to work with the second time it runs

Comment: One idea might be to build a string representation of the number, and then inspect that. It's often handy since (decimal) strings make accessing digits in left-to-right order trivial.

Comment: actually the problem is that I am really a beginner in c and I only know how to work with integers, floats,conditions, and loops

Comment: upper case variables are macros!

Comment: What u need postion of digit  `p` or the digit at position `p`

Comment: @user8: Variables with upper-case names are variables.

Comment: I need the digit at position p@RajeevSingh

Comment: Will the idea of two loops seems legit going to try it and tell you the results @user3121023

Comment: @AliHaroon The Value of `N` is not changing in loop.

Comment: yes I know but do you have any idea how can I change it ? @AkaSh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you count the number of digits in the integer,let say `n`.Then you can get the first digit by dividing the number by **10<sup>n-1</sup>**.Then put this in a loop and decrease **n** by **1** & number **N** by 
**N%=10<sup>n-1</sup>**

```
int main()
{
    int i,j=0,p,N;
    printf("Enter two positive integers: ");
    scanf("%d%d",&N,&p);

    int pow=1,tmp=N;
    //counting power of 10 to divide
    while(tmp>10)
    {
        pow*=10;
        tmp/=10;
    }
    tmp=N;
    for(i=1; i<=p;i++){
       j = tmp/pow;
       tmp%=pow;
       pow/=10;
    }
    printf("The digit of %d in the position %d is %d\n",N,p,j);
}
```

Comment: This is it @RajeevSingh the program worked as wanted

Comment: Let me know if u find any bugs!!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int p=5;
    int n = 123456;
    int digits[12]={};

    j=n;
    while(j)
    {
        digits[i]=j%10;
        j = j/10;
        i++;
    }

     printf("The digit of %d in the position %d is %d",n,p,digits[i-p]);
     return 0;
}
```

The easiest way for me to design is to convert the integer to digits and look up.

Why this way:

To avoid `pow`, `log10` because they need floating point support to run, and hardware floating point to run fast.

And to avoid two loops because those two loops does a lot of repeated calculation.

http://ideone.com/Vo9g6T

Comment: Your code assumes that number will have maximum 12 digits.

Comment: in your example you (as the programmer) is defining all the variables while I want the user to enter the number and position so that the program  can tell him about the position

Comment: @AliHaroon I hate command line parsing and I'm only interested in the "business logic". So sorry I intentionally left that to you (or whoever want to) to solve.

Comment: @AkaSh I think that's a design requirement. Like if you give it an input of 11 digits, it's like to overflow `int` anyway. So we need to limit the number of digits somehow to choose a data type for it (like `int32_t, uint64_t`), then choose the buffer size. This answer assumes the limitation is 32 bit int and `int` is 32 bit int, which is the my "best educated guess what the user needs" when the requirement is missing.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can do this. As some of the comment suggests, you can do either of the following:

**Method 1:**
Convert the number into a string array, which can be accomplished by `sprintf`.

```
char str[256];
int len = sprintf(str,"%d",N);
//traverse str using len
```

**Method 2:**
Since a number N with n digits in base b you can express any number up to `pow(b,n)-1`. To get the digit you can use the inverse function of `pow`, namely base-b logarithm. You may not get integer values, so you can use the `floor` and cast the result to int. The full program looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int getDigit(int num, int p)
{
   return (num / (int)pow(10, floor(log10(num)) - p)) % 10;
}

int main()
{
    int i,j=0,p,q,N;// N is the integer and p is the position needed
    printf("Enter two positive integers: ");
    scanf("%d%d",&N,&p);// Taking the values of N and p
    j = getDigit(N,p);
    //The result is j if you count from 0, j+1 if you count from 1
    printf("The digit of %d in the position %d is %d\n",N,p,j+1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually it has been asked a lot on SO why `pow` returns a result 1 smaller. Answer was `pow` calculates in double and a small error can cause rounding to round to the smaller integer. I guess you need to round to nearest integer to be safe.

Comment: Regarding method two I find this calculation easier to understand ((int)(number/pow(10, position - 1))) % 10

Answer (score 0):

Without using 2 loops :

```
int main()
{
    int i,ans,p,N,no_of_digits=0,temp;
    printf("Enter two positive integers: ");
    scanf("%d%d",&N,&p);
    temp=N;
    no_of_digits=(int)log10(N) + 1;
    while(i<=(no_of_digits-p))
    {
        ans=N%10;
        N=N/10;
        i++;
    }
    printf("The digit of %d in the position %d is %d\n",temp,p,ans);
}
```

http://ideone.com/kQFISY

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getDgtLen (int n);

int main(void)
{
    // n is the integer and p is the position needed
    int i, q, n, p;

    // Prompt for taking the values of n and p
    do
    {
        printf("Enter two positive integers for number,  position: ");
        scanf("%d%d", &n, &p);
    }
    while (n < 0 || p <= 0);

    int nOrigin = n;
    int len = getDgtLen(n);

    if (p <= len)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < p; i++)
        {
            q = n % 10;
            n /= 10;
        }
        printf("The digit of %d in the position %d is %d\n", nOrigin, p, len - q + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("position not found!\n");
    }
}

int getDgtLen (int n)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        n /= 10;
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```